# Object rotation while moving on a path in Flash

Tags: flash

I have a movieclip moving on a path by means of a tween. At the starting point a (virtual) line on the movieclip is tangent to the path. Is there an easy way to automagically rotate the movieclip such that this line remains tangent to the path throughout the tween?
[image]
TIA
Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it.

For those interested:
Click somewhere on the tween on the timeline. In the properties check "Orient to path". `Important:` make sure that the object has the same orientation with respect to the path on the first and the last frame of the tween.